# Cloud Firestore - How to paginate data with RXJS

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

I would like to get data from the Cloud Firestore collection (limited to 10), and then after clicking the "load more" button, I would like to get another piece of collection and concat with the previous result.

My code is (base on https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors):

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../../shared/models/user';
import { UsersService } from '../../../shared/services/users.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  users: User[];
  lastInResponse: any;
  subscription:Subscription;

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.usersService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.lastInResponse = res[res.length - 1]; // the last object in response
        this.users = res;
      }
    )
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  loadMore() {
    this.subscription = this.usersService.loadMoreData('users', this.lastInResponse)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.lastInResponse = res[res.length - 1];
        this.users = this.users.concat(res); //concat new values with prevoius
      }
    );
    
  }

}
```

It works fine, but I would like to clean my code and subscribe to users collection with **a more reactive** style, like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
.
.
.
.

users$: Observable<User[]>;
.
.
.
.

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.users$ = this.usersService.getUsers();
}
```

and then use the "async" pipe in the HTML template.

My question is how could I refactor my code? Especially how to extract the last object in response and then pass it to loadMore() method and finally concat another value with previous.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code -

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../../shared/models/user';
import { UsersService } from '../../../shared/services/users.service';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import {filter, switchMap, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  // lets setup a behavior subject to hold the users to be rendered; I have initialized the list with empty array; you can initialized to null as per your need
  usersToRender$ = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([]);
  
  // this will be used to ensure that the initial users list will be fetched
  initialUsers$: Observable<User[]>;
  
  // this will be used to notify that the user has requested to loadMore data
  loadMore$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  fetchMore$: Observable<any>;
  
  lastInResponse: any;

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  
    this.initialUsers$ = this.usersService.getUsers()
                                         .pipe(
                                                tap(res => {
                                                    this.lastInResponse = res[res.length - 1];
                                                    this.usersToRender$.next(res);
                                                }),
                                              );
    
    this.setupLoadMoreObservable();
  }

  private setupLoadMoreObservable() {
    
    this.fetchMore$ = this.loadMore$.pipe(
                        filter(l => l === true),
                        switchMap(() => {
                            return this.usersService.loadMoreData('users', this.lastInResponse)
                        }),
                        tap(res => {
                            this.lastInResponse = res[res.length - 1];
                            this.usersToRender$.next([...this.usersToRender$.getValue(), ...res]);
                            this.loadMore$.next(false);
                        })
                      )
    
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    
  }

  loadMore() {
    this.loadMore$.next(true);
  }

}
```

In the template add the following code. Also, use `usersToRender$` to render the users

```
<ng-container *ngIf="initialUsers$ | async"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="fetchMore$ | async"></ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But one thing more... Let's assume, I'd like to use it in several components (for instance, load more orders, products, etc). Wouldn't it be accurate to extract setupLoadMoreObservablemethod() as an exported function and then import this method on the top of the component? I'd like to avoid code repetition.

Comment: You can have a service to write the reusable function and that service could be injected into desired components. Service is the best way to have reusable code.