# Firebase - How to paginate using RxJS - the final peace

Tags: angular, firebase, pagination

I saw this post: [Cloud Firestore - How to paginate data with RXJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63921721/cloud-firestore-how-to-paginate-data-with-rxjs)

This is exactly what I need but I don't understand how to reproduce the

```
import { UsersService } from '../../../shared/services/users.service';
```

I just need to understand what is inside this service because I can't make a function work like both `getUsers()` and `loadMoreData()`. I'm learning the new MODULAR approach on AngularFire and the answer above is the one I need to understand to properly implement pagination.

What I had done so far:

```js
import {
  collection,
  collectionData,
  Firestore,
  limit,
  orderBy,
  query,
  startAfter
} from "@angular/fire/firestore";


querySnapshot:any;
lastInResponse:any;


  constructor( private stringEmitted: StringBridgeService, private firestore: Firestore ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stringEmitted.stringChanged(this.actualTitle);
    this.loadCustomers('customers', 'name', 5)
  }


  loadCustomers(collectionName:string, order:string, max:number) {
    return collectionData(query(collection(this.firestore, collectionName), orderBy(order), limit(max))).subscribe(
      response => {
        // @ts-ignore
        this.lastInResponse = response[response.length - 1];
        this.querySnapshot = response;
      }
    );
  }

  loadMore(data:object) {
    return collectionData(query(collection(this.firestore, 'customers'), orderBy('name'), limit(5), startAfter(data))).subscribe(
      response => {
        // @ts-ignore
        this.lastInResponse = response[response.length - 1];
        this.querySnapshot = this.querySnapshot.concat(response);
      }
    );
  }

  myTest() {
    console.log(this.lastInResponse);
  }
```

I only have ONE problem with this code `ERROR FirebaseError: Function startAfter() called with invalid data`. The function `myTest()` writes the correct data from the last customer to the console but still the error appears.

What is the right type of data? How could I convert?

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the solution!

```js
import {
  collection,
  collectionData,
  Firestore,
  limit,
  orderBy,
  query,
  startAfter
} from "@angular/fire/firestore";


querySnapshot:any;
lastInResponse:any;


  constructor( private stringEmitted: StringBridgeService, private firestore: Firestore ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stringEmitted.stringChanged(this.actualTitle);
    this.loadCustomers('customers', 'name', 5)
  }


  loadCustomers(collectionName:string, order:string, max:number) {
    return collectionData(query(collection(this.firestore, collectionName), orderBy(order), limit(max))).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.lastInResponse = response[response.length - 1];
        this.querySnapshot = response;
      }
    );
  }

  loadMore(data:any) {
    if(this.lastInResponse){
      return collectionData(query(collection(this.firestore, 'customers'), orderBy('name'), limit(3), startAfter(data['name']))).subscribe(
        response => {
          this.lastInResponse = response[response.length - 1];
          this.querySnapshot = this.querySnapshot.concat(response);
          // this.querySnapshot = response;
        }
      );
    }
    return null
  }

  myTest() {
    console.log(this.lastInResponse);
  }
```

`startAfter()` requires, in my case, the last name on my list. The true **modular** approach was used here.

Thank you all!